# ContentValues is missordering the fields of the table, why? and how to solve?

Tags: android, database, insert, android-sqlite

Good morning every body;

I'm trying to make a database class in android, and it is done, I've created a table successfully too. The problem comes when I want to insert rows to the table using `ContentValues`, it tries to insert the row in different order from the table fields which cuases an error in the logcat saying : no such table as follows:

These are my variables:

```
    private static final String row_ID="RID";
    private static final String row_NAME="NAME";
    private static final String row_EMAIL="EMAIL";
    private static final String row_WEBSITE="WEBSITE";
    private static final String row_TELEPHONE1="PHONE_NUMBER1";
    private static final String row_TELEPHONE2="PHONE_NUMBER2";
    private static final String row_TELEPHONE3="PHONE_NUMBER3";
    private static final String row_TELEPHONE4="PHONE_NUMBER4";
    private static final String row_TELEPHONE5="PHONE_NUMBER5";
    private static final String db_NAME="ContactsDb";
    private static final String tab_NAME="ContactsTab";
    private static final int db_VERSION=2;
    private dbHelper ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;
```

My table :

```
    String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE " + db_NAME + " ("
                            + row_ID + " INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                            + row_NAME + " TEXT, "
                            + row_EMAIL + " TEXT, "
                            + row_WEBSITE + " TEXT, "
                            + row_TELEPHONE1 + " TEXT, "
                            + row_TELEPHONE2 + " TEXT, "
                            + row_TELEPHONE3 + " TEXT, "
                            + row_TELEPHONE4 + " TEXT, "
                            + row_TELEPHONE5 + " TEXT);";
        db_name.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
```

Inserting rows using `ContentValues` :

```
    public long createEntry(String name, String email, String website, String telephone1, String telephone2, String telephone3, String telephone4, String telephone5)
{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues ();

    Log.v("STATUS", "getting input data..");

    cv.put(row_NAME, name);
    cv.put(row_EMAIL, email);
    cv.put(row_WEBSITE, website);       
    cv.put(row_TELEPHONE1, telephone1);
    cv.put(row_TELEPHONE2, telephone2);
    cv.put(row_TELEPHONE3, telephone3);
    cv.put(row_TELEPHONE4, telephone4);
    cv.put(row_TELEPHONE5, telephone5);
    Log.v("STATUS", "got input data, inserting data....");

    return ourDatabase.insert(tab_NAME, null, cv);
}
```

So, when I run this application it succeeds doing all these until it arrives to `ourDatabase.insert(tab_NAME, null, cv);` it shows the error:

```
    SQLiteLog            (1) no such table: ContactsTab
    SQLiteDatabase       Error inserting Name=Ahlam M. Hussain   PHONE_NUMBER5=
                         PHONE_NUMBER4=   PHONE_NUMBER3=    PHONE_NUMBER2=059999999
                         PHONE_NUMBER1= 09299999    EMAIL=ahlam@ahlam.com    EWEBSITE=
    SQLiteDatabase       android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table:
                         ContactsTab (code 1): ,while compiling: INSERT INTO
                         ContactsTab(NAME, PHONE_NUMBER5 PHONE_NUMBER4 PHONE_NUMBER3
                         PHONE_NUMBER2 PHONE_NUMBER1, EMAIL, WEBSITE) VALUES
                         (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

You can notice that it is trying to insert row in different fields orderm so it is not recognizing the table..

So what to do ??? I really got suck of that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to set brace on

- row_TELEPHONE5 + " TEXT;";

it has to be

- row_TELEPHONE5 + " TEXT);";

### EDIT

try it with "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" and "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" not "INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT". Also You had set db_name instead of table_name in your CREATE-TABLE String. Change it to your table_name:

```
     String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tab_NAME + " ("
                        + row_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                        + row_NAME + " TEXT, "
                        + row_EMAIL + " TEXT, "
                        + row_WEBSITE + " TEXT, "
                        + row_TELEPHONE1 + " TEXT, "
                        + row_TELEPHONE2 + " TEXT, "
                        + row_TELEPHONE3 + " TEXT, "
                        + row_TELEPHONE4 + " TEXT, "
                        + row_TELEPHONE5 + " TEXT);";
    db_name.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
```

Comment: You are the best.. thanks alot.. that's it ..!! the table name..!! thanks again.. it works perfectly